# " django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 5: 'get_verbose_name', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. "

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have been searching for ways to display data from Django models in a view/template. I am still just a beginner but have read a lot of stackoverflow to gain knowledge.

The implementation of what I am trying to do I picked up from this thread: [Display table of objects django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615847/display-table-of-objects-django)

After inputting the template.html and the views.py (slightly modifying my views.py - changing MyModel to the Environment Model) I am getting the error :

`"Invalid block tag on line 5: 'get_verbose_name', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?"`

This error is referring to the `<th>{% get_verbose_name field %}</th>`

in template.html

I have tried to add a verbose name to every field in the model but this is not the apparent issue. Attached in a pastebin is my views.py, models.py and template.html.

My views.py and template.html are almost exactly the same as the solution checked in the linked stackoverflow thread. My issue is basically understanding why this error exists, and how I can resolve it

Thank you for your help

## tables.html

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        {% for field in cached_fields %}
            <th>{% get_verbose_name field %}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
        {% for d in data %}
            <tr>
                {% for field in fields %}
                    <td>{% get_value_from_key d field %}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

## Views.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.views import generic
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, get_object_or_404,     redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.http import HttpRequest, HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext
import simplejson as json
#from appDatabase.forms import *
from . import forms;
from . import models;

class AppTable(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = "appDatabase/tables.html"

def index(request) :
    fields    = Environment._meta.fields
    data      = json.loads(serializers.serialize("json", Environment.objects.all()))

    def parse_data(data):

        result = []

        # flatten the dictionary
        def flatten_dict(d):
            """
            Because the only nested dict here is the fields, let's just
            remove the 'fields' suffix so that the fields can be loaded in
            template by name
            """
            def items():
                for key, value in d.items():
                    if isinstance(value, dict):
                        for subkey, subvalue in flatten_dict(value).items():
                            yield subkey, subvalue
                    else:
                        yield key, value

            return dict(items())
        for d in data:
            # change the 'pk' key name into its actual name in the database
            d[Environment._meta.pk.name] = d.pop('pk')
            # append the flattend dict of each object's field-value to the result
            result.append(flatten_dict(d))

        return result

        context_instance  = RequestContext(request, {
        'data'      : parse_data(data),
        'fields'    : fields, })
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'tables.html', context_instance)
```

## Models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
import uuid
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm;
# Create your models here.


class Environment(CommonInfo):
    environment_Type = models.CharField(verbose_name ="Environment Type", max_length=10)
    environment_Name = models.CharField(verbose_name ="Environment Name", max_length=10)
```

Comment: no tag called `get_verbose_name`

Comment: you need to register new tag

Comment: You need to create a custom template tag and make it available in your template. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags

Answer (score 5):

- **Very Simple Approach**

use `{{field.verbose_name}}` instead of `{% get_value_from_key d field %}` in your template this approach working fine and tested :

```
In [1]: from django.template import Template,Context

In [2]: t=Template("""""")

In [3]: t=Template("""{% for field in fields %}
   ...:                     <td>{{field.verbose_name}}</td>
   ...:                 {% endfor %}""")

In [4]: from h.models import MyClass

In [5]: c = Context({"fields":MyClass._meta.fields,})

In [6]: t.render(c)
Out[6]: u'\n                    <td>ID</td>\n                \n                    <td>Name</td>\n
```

- **very complex approach**

First of all you will need to register Custom template tag according to django [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags):

The app should contain a `templatetags` directory, at the same level as `models.py`, `views.py`, etc. If this doesn’t already exist, create it - don’t forget the `__init__.py` file to ensure the directory is treated as a Python package.
then create python file name it as you want here file name `mytag.py`
near the top of your module, put the following:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()
```

to register tag use function helper `simple_tag`
before your function add :

```
@register.simple_tag
```

then type your tag as function it takes two arguments `instance` and `name`(i.e filed name) then return `verbose_name` :

```
def get_verbose_name(instance):
    return instance.verbose_name
```

put all together :

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()
@register.simple_tag
def get_verbose_name(instance, field_name):
       return instance.verbose_name
```

then to use it in your template load `mytag` module the use tag:

```
{% load mytag %} 
{% get_verbose_name field_instance %}
```

return field_instance.verbose_name

Comment: `{% get_verbose_name field_instance "name_of_field" %}` should read `{% get_verbose_name field_instance %}` the `field_instance` contains the `verbose_name`. So the filter needs to do something like: `return field_instance.verbose_name` and maybe write a fall back if the verbose_name is not present (fallback to `field_name` itself?). Both properties live in the `field_instance`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, And kudos for considering the OP's level of understanding :p